# passing strings to functions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a variable to pass a string to the serial.Serial function in python. The following works the way I want it to:

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0)
```

However if I try to put the string into a variable like so and then call the function with the variable I get an error.

```
serialString = '"/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0'

port = serial.Serial(serialString)
```

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./cncserver.py", line 34,
>   in 
>       port = serial.Serial(serialString)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in
>   **init**
>       self.open()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in
>   open
>       raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg)) serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port
>   "/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0:
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '"/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0'

I'm guessing it's something to do with the filepath in the string not being quoted properly but I've spent enough time trying to figure it out, can somebody help me here please?

Thanks, 
  Lorne

Here is my revised code:

```
#parameter settings of the serial port on the PI must match the control
serialPort = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
serialBaudRate = 9600
serialByteSize = serial.SEVENBITS
serialStopBits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
serialParity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
serialTimeout = 3.0

port = serial.Serial(serialPort,serialBaudRate,serialByteSize,serialStopBits,serialParity,serialTimeout)
```

Here is the new error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./cncserver.py", line 39,
>   in 
>       port = serial.Serial(serialPort,serialBaudRate,serialByteSize,serialStopBits,serialParity,serialTimeout)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line
>   250, in **init**
>       self.parity   = parity   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 344, in
>   setParity
>       if parity not in self.PARITIES: raise ValueError("Not a valid parity: %r" % (parity,)) ValueError: Not a valid parity: 1

Comment: Why are you even trying that if you already know how to do it properly?

Comment: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports

Comment: @StefanPochmann, I want to use variables so I can define them at the top of the file then use them later on in my code. Is this not good practice?

Comment: @user3140383 No that's good practice. Do it right, though. Since you seem to want all parameters to be constant, I'd probably just use your original `port =` at the top of the file. Alternatively, specify each parameter there, or specify a dictionary for the keyword arguments and then use that later.

Answer (score 3):

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0)
```

is not the same as

```
port = serial.Serial('"/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0')
```

This is not a string, but function parameters that have been passed as key_pair values.

```
"/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0
```

sends 6 different parameters to the function, :-

1. /dev/ttyAMA0
2. baudrate as 9600
3. bytesize as serial.SEVENBITS
4. stopbits as serial.STOPBITS_ONE
5. parity as serial.PARITY_EVEN
6. timeout as 3.0

   `'"/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0'`

sends only one parameter as

1. '"/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600,bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,timeout=3.0'

as for what you are trying to do,

initialize :

```
args = ("/dev/ttyAMA0",)
kwargs= {'baudrate':9600,'bytesize':serial.SEVENBITS,'stopbits':serial.STOPBITS_ONE,'parity':serial.PARITY_EVEN,'timeout':3.0}
```

and call them wherever you want

```
port = serial.Serial(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks @Namit, I realized this and was revising my code while you posted :), however I am still getting an error, I will edit my original question .

Comment: @user3140383 try the solution above now

Comment: Thanks, I will try that next week.